# Why can we think of $F^n$ as $F^{\{1,2,...,n\}}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, elementary-set-theory

I understand why $F^S$ (where S is a set) is a vector space. I just don't see why we can think of $F^n$ as $F^{\{1,2,...,n\}}$. I saw someone saying that we can think of $\mathbb{R}^3$ as the set of functions from ${\{1,2,3\}}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, but how can a *function* be a *number* in $\mathbb{R}$? Or do they mean the *result* of the function?
I'm self-learning math so I apologise if the answer is obvious.

Comment: What *is* $\Bbb R^3$ for you?

Comment: More importantly, if $\Bbb R^3$ is a space of $3$-tuples, how can a *tuple* be a *number*?

Comment: @Asaf Karagila I always thought of $\mathbb{R}$ as the space containing all possible combinations of 3 real numbers.

Comment: Okay, so either a combination of numbers is a number, or your comment about "how can a function be a number in $\Bbb R$" is irrelevant here. Because $(0,0,1)$ and $(1,0,0)$ are not the same vector, even though it's "almost the same combination".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f$ is a function from $\{1,2,3\}$ into $\mathbb R$, then $\bigl(f(1),f(2),f(3)\bigr)\in\mathbb{R}^3$. And if $(a,b,c)\in\mathbb{R}^3$, then you can define a function $f$ from $\{1,2,3\}$ into the reals by $f(1)=a$, $f(2)=b$, and $f(3)=c$. So, there is a bijection between $\mathbb{R}^3$ and the set of all functions from $\{1,2,3\}$ into $\mathbb R$.

By the same argument, there is a natural way of identifying $F^n$ with the set of all functions from $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ into $F$.

Comment: Thank you, I think I get it. You use the output of the function, not the function itself.

Answer (score 2):

Mathematically speaking, the @José Carlos Santos is the right one, and is the one teached in universtity classes.

What you probably need is a more "semantic" tranlsation of that answer. Let's try:

$\mathbb R^3$ is the set of triples $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ where $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are real numbers. Right? Now, what does it mean "$x_1$"? "$x_1$" is the number that  *corresponds* to the place $1$. So $x_2$ is the number that *corresponds* to the place $2$, and so on.

Therefore, $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ is in fact a *correspondence* from the set of *places* $1,2,3$ to the set of real numbers, that is to say a function from $\{1,2,3\}$ to $\mathbb R$.